# In-place editing of multiple files in a directory using Perl's diamond and in-place edit operator

Tags: perl

I am trying to in-place edit a bunch of text files using Perl's in-place edit operator $^I. I traverse through the directory using the diamond (<>) operator like this:

```
$^I = ".bak";

@ARGV = <*.txt>;

while (<>)
{
    s/((?:^|\s)-?)(0+)(?=\s|$)/$1.$2/g;
    print;
}
```

This works perfectly and does the job I need it to do. But what if my @ARGV is already populated with some other data I need for the program? I tried to do the following:

```
$^I = ".bak";

my @files = <*.txt>;

while (<@files>)
{
    s/((?:^|\s)-?)(0+)(?=\s|$)/$1.$2/g;
    print;
}
```

But it does not work. What I am I missing here? I can't use my $ARGV as it contains other data and can't mess it with file matching patterns.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy your arguments beforehand, and then use `@ARGV`. E.g.:

```
my @args = @ARGV;
@ARGV = <*.txt>;
```

Since there is some hidden processing going on, which is specific to the use of `@ARGV` and the diamond operator `<>`, you cannot just use another array to do the same thing.

Comment: I actually thought about this approach already. But I thought I was making mistakes in the way I was using the diamond operator. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to do this without creating a copy of ARGV first?

Comment: @GolamKawsar Of course. But not as easily. You could simply write out the code which does the in-place edit in full. I'm not sure what the purpose of this would be, though.

Comment: @GolamKawsar the behavior of unadorned `while (<>)` is tied to the so-called "magic `ARGV`" filehandle, which (unsurprisingly based on its name) is connected with the `@ARGV` array. If you want the one, you need to use the other. The alternative, as @TLP says, is not to use magic-`ARGV` or `$^I` at all and write the equivalent code yourself.

Comment: @Golam Kawsar, Use a reference if you want to avoid a copy: `my $orig_ARGV = \@ARGV; local @ARGV = <*.txt>; ...;` Mind you, that sounds like "premature" optimisation.

Answer (score 4):

You can give `@ARGV` a temporary value with the `local` keyword:

```
{
    local @ARGV = <*.txt>;
    while (<>) {...}
} # @ARGV gets the old value back
```

Comment: But then you cannot access the arguments while parsing the files.

Comment: @TLP: that's true. But luckily in this case I don't need the arguments in the while block!
I think this is a neat approach!

Comment: @GolamKawsar It's actually the same approach as mine, except using `local` to create a copy of `@ARGV`, instead of `my`.

Comment: @TLP: Except this copying is hidden from you and is transparently taken care of by Perl :)

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just store the information from @ARGV that you still need into another variable?

```
$^I = ".bak";

my @options = @ARGV;
@ARGV = <*.txt>;

while (<>)
{
    s/((?:^|\s)-?)(0+)(?=\s|$)/$1.$2/g;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Iterator::Files, see  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Iterator::Diamond  for reasons why

```
use Iterator::Files;
my $input = Iterator::Files->new( files => [ glob "*.txt" ] );
while( <$input> ){
    s/((?:^|\s)-?)(0+)(?=\s|$)/$1.$2/g;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach for this is to process the arguments and save the files off in a temporary list, then stuff them back into @ARGV.

```
my @files;
foreach (@ARGV) {
    ... do something with each parm
    else {
        push @files,$_;
    }
}
@ARGV=@files;
while (<>) {
    ...
```

Usually, in the foreach (@ARGV) I will do something like

```
if (-f) {
    push @files,$_;
    next;
}
```