# Perl: Replace strings in multiple files with array entry

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I am looking for a simple way to replace strings in multiple text files. In the first file the string should be replaced with the first element of the array `@arrayF`; in the second file the string must be replaced with the second entry etc.

I want to replace `;size=\d+` where `\d+` is a wildcard for any number.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $counter = 0;
my @arrayF  = '/Users/majuss/Desktop/filelist.txt>';  # Reads all lines into array
my @files   = '/Users/majuss/Desktop/New_Folder/*'; #get Files into an array

foreach my $file ( @files ) {
  $file =~ s/;size=\d+/$arrayF[$counter]/g; #subst. 
  print
  $counter++; #increment array index
}
```

It gives a zero back and nothing happens.

I know how to do it in a one-liner but I can't figure a way out how to implement an array there.

Comment: you probably want to use the options /ge at the end instead of just /g.  See perldoc perlre

Comment: Your '@files' isn't expanding the pattern. You need `my @files = glob ( '/Users/majuss/Desktop/New_Folder/*' );` You're also not opening or reading 'filelist.txt' - you need to use `open`.

Comment: The lines commented `Reads all lines into array` and `get Files into an array` aren't doing that. You need to *open* the file and read it in the first case, and use `glob` in the second case. Also, please don't use upper-case letters in your local identifiers, and don't use `-w` on the shebang line as well as `use warnings`; just the latter is correct

Comment: If you have the `-w` switch you don't need `use warnings` (or vice-versa); they do the same thing. You don't need the `/g` on your regex if there's only one `;size=` string per line. Otherwise, as others have pointed out, you're not reading a list of files or reading in each file or really doing anything you've set out to do. :-)

Comment: @mwp: Given that the OP's code doesn't do any file IO at all I think your comments are superfluous

Answer (score 0):

- You're not opening `filelist.txt` and reading it.

Do do this you need to:

```
open ( my $input, "<", '/Users/majuss/Desktop/filelist.txt' ) or die $!;
my @arrayF = <$input>;
close ( $input );
```

- You need to use `glob` to search a directory pattern like that.

Like this:

```
foreach my $file ( glob ( '/Users/majuss/Desktop/New_Folder/*' ) {
      # stuff
}
```

- To search and replace within a file, it's actually a bit different to a one liner. You can look at 'in place editing' in [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) - but this is where perl is trying to pretend to be `sed`. I think you can do it if you try - there's an option in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> $^I
>   The current value of the inplace-edit extension. Use undef to disable inplace editing.
>   Mnemonic: value of -i switch.

This answer may give some insight:
[In-place editing of multiple files in a directory using Perl's diamond and in-place edit operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232059/in-place-editing-of-multiple-files-in-a-directory-using-perls-diamond-and-in-pl)

Instead you can:

```
foreach my $file ( glob  ( '/Users/majuss/Desktop/New_Folder/*' ) {
     open ( my $input_fh, "<", $file ) or die $!;
     open ( my $output_fh, ">", "$file.NEW" ) or die $!;
     my $replace = shift ( @arrayF );
     while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
        $line =~ s/;size=\d+/$replace/g; 
        print {$output_fh} $line;
     }
     close ( $input_fh );
     close ( $output_fh );
      #rename 'output'. 
}
```

Comment: Close. Your parens are wrong on the first line and I think you need to set `$replace` _before_ the inner while-loop (one value per file). The `/g` on your regex is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Note these points that I commented on beneath your question

- The line commented `Reads all lines into array` doesn't do that. It simply sets `@arrayF` to a one-element list that holds the string `/Users/majuss/Desktop/filelist.txt>`. You probably need to *open* the file and read its contents into an array
- The line commented `get Files into an array` doesn't do that. It simply sets `@files` to a one-element list that holds the string `/Users/majuss/Desktop/New_Folder/*`. You probably need to use `glob` to expand the wildcard into a list of files
- The statement

  ```
  $file =~ s/;size=\d+/$arrayF[$counter]/g
  ```

  is attempting to modify the variable `$file` which contains the *name* of the file. Presumably you meant to edit the *contents* of that file, so you must open and read it first
- Please don't use upper-case letters in your local identifiers
- Don't use `-w` on the shebang line as well as `use warnings`; just the latter is correct

This seems to do what you're asking for, but be aware that it is *untested* except that I have checked that it will compile. Be careful that you have a backup of the original files as this code will overwrite the original files with the modified data

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my $replacement_text = '/Users/majuss/Desktop/filelist.txt';
my $file_glob        = '/Users/majuss/Desktop/New_Folder/*';

my @replacement_text = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $replacement_text;
  <$fh>;
};
chomp @replacement_text;

my $i = 0;

for my $file ( glob $file_glob ) {

  my $contents = do {
    open my $in_fh, '<', $file;
    local $/;
    <$in_fh>;
  };

  $contents =~ s/;size=\d+/$replacement_text[$i]/g;

  open my $out_fh, '>', $file;
  print $out_fh $contents;

  ++$i;
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `<$fh>` in your `do` to set `@file_list`. And I think you want `print {$out_fh} $contents` or `$out_fh->print($contents)` at the end there. And as I've pointed out elsewhere, the `/g` is superfluous.

Comment: @mwp: Thanks. I agree about the missing file read, but my `print $out_fh $contents` is fine, and the `/g` modifier is required if there are multiple occurrences of the pattern in the file

Comment: Sure. It's computationally wasteful if multiple occurrences aren't expected, but that's probably the least of the OP's problems at this point in time.